# Input validation using typeof

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on input validation, I dont want to use RegExp but I keep wondering why typeof is not working inside if statement or is anything wrong with my code

```js
function myDom(){
    
    var message = document.getElementById('show');
    var xx = document.getElementById('demo').value;
    try{
        if(xx === "") throw "can not be empty";
        if(typeof xx === "number") throw "can not be number";
        //if(xx < 100) throw "less than hundreds!"
   }catch(err){
       message.innerHTML = "input " + err;
   }
    
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('demo').value` will always be `string` - since (assuming `#demo` is an input) input.value is always a string

Comment: by the way ... if xx cannot be a number, why is the commented out comparison even there?

Comment: well when I use typeof Number(xx) it still misbehaves.

Comment: `it still misbehaves` in what way? what is the result of `typeof Number(xx)` : hint, `typeof Number('anything')` will **always** be a number, right - try using isNaN (well, !isNaN actually)

Comment: or `Number(xx).toString() === xx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of input ***value*** is always ***string***. Since you are comparing with strictly equality operator (`===`), you have to convert them to ***number***. You should convert the value only if the value is only number using (*isNaN*) or not empty:

```
var elValue = document.getElementById('demo').value;
var xx = isNaN(elValue) || elValue == '' ? elValue: Number(elValue);
```

**Demo:**

```js
function myDom(){
  var message = document.getElementById('show');
  var elValue = document.getElementById('demo').value.trim();
  var xx = isNaN(elValue) || elValue == '' ? elValue: Number(elValue);
  try{
    if(xx === "") throw "can not be empty";
    else if(typeof xx === "number") throw "can not be number";
    else message.innerHTML = '';
    //if(xx < 100) throw "less than hundreds!"
  }catch(err){
    message.innerHTML = "input " + err;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="demo" oninput="myDom()"/>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: this won't be ideal if xx is  empty ''"